# How do I get back into my system when I have forgot my password for the "Lock My PC" tool?

Tags: windows-7, password-recovery, lock

I am using a PC locking software(Lock My PC) to prevent unauthorized access to my desktop computer at my office, but after I changed my password, it seems that I forgot it. is there any trick to get in into the system without any reinstalling Windows?  The software allows to enter to the OS but it freezes the screen so the mouse will not be able to move and not able to click on anything either.
I am using Win 7/

Comment: You can try safe mode.  If that doesn't work then you are out of luck.

Comment: @Ramhound that will not work since I already did it at this morning in Pacific time hehe

Answer (score 2):

#### I have forgotten my password for the "Lock My PC tool?

Use the "Lock My PC Administrative Area". From here you can clear the current user password. You may have to boot into safe mode first...

> To enter Lock My PC Administrative Area please run Lock My PC Administrative Area shortcut. If you don't have Administrative Area shortcut installed just run Lock My PC program file with "/a" command line parameter (C:\Program Files\LMPC\lockpc /a). The program will prompt you to enter Lock My PC administrator's password you have specified when install. If you enter a correct administrator's password "Administrative Area" dialog will appear.

Source [Lock My PC Administrator's Guide](http://fspro.net/lock-my-pc/adminarea.html)

---

#### In safe mode, of course, the screen is still frozen/locked

You will to contact [FSPro support](http://fspro.net/contacts.html) for help.

Comment: but...but I cannot unlock my computer to run the administrator area. in safe mode, of course, the screen is still frozen/locked.

Answer (score 0):

windows password reset tool called Hiren boot CD.You can boot from usb also

Tested on: NT 3.51, NT 4 (all versions and SPs), Windows 2000 (all versions & SPs), Windows XP (all versions, also SP2 and SP3), Windows Server 2003 (all SPs), Windows Vista 32 and 64 bit (SP1 also), Window 7 (all variants). Some also say that it works on Windows Server 2008 too.
If used on users that have EFS encrypted files, and the system is XP or Vista, all encrypted files for that user will be UNREADABLE! and cannot be recovered unless you remember the old password again. If you don't know if you have encrypted files or not, you most likely don't have them (except maybe on corporate systems).

refer hiren official sites for steps for using the tool